# How do I count the words in a string using only loops and string.strip()?

Tags: python, string, count

So this is the function I have so far. It's supposed to read a text file and return the total number of words. I'm only allowed to use `for` loops, `while` loops, and `string.strip()`. For some strange reason it's counting some extra character from text file, including newlines. Here's one of the text files:

`Words make up other words.
This is a line.
  Sequences of words make sentences.
I like words but I don't like MS Word.
    There's another word for how I feel about MSWord: @#%&`

In this text file it has a total of 33 words but my program is counting 34. Each sentence is on its own line. The third line has two leading spaces; the fifth line has 4 tab spaces.

```
def countWords(textFileName):
    words = 0
    for char in textFileName:
        if char == " " or char == ".":
            words = words + 1
        if char != " " and char != ".":
            pass
    return words


def main():
    textFileName = input("Enter textFileName: ")
    total = 0
    for line in open(textFileName):
        total = total + countWords(line)
    print(total, "words")
main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more complicated than line.strip()"? Are you in fact disallowed from using `str.split`?

Comment: @das-g I can only use _for loops_ ,  _while_ loops and str.strip(). No other Python functionality.

Comment: The fifth line of your example file had a tab character in front, not eight spaces. I've changed it to match your description, but that might also change the result your current code will give for it.

Comment: In `countWords` you seem to be counting spaces and periods, rather than words. This will give you the false result, because words might be separated by several spaces and/or periods. Also, you'll miss words at line ends.

Comment: @das-g Thanks for the edit! I'm new to this so please excuse my mistakes.

Comment: @das-g The way I'm supposed to approach this is to look at each line in the file and scan for whitespace, i.e. only space and tab characters. We consider a consecutive sequence of whitespace a single block. By removing leading and trailing whitespace, counting the number of whitespace blocks and then adding 1, we get the number of words in one line of text.

Comment: @das-g It actually has 4 tab spaces on the last line in the text file.

Comment: This feels like a homework question. If so, the restrictions are there to force you into thinking of a solution within those restrictions. As such, it's more an exercise in thinking than programming. We would be doing you no favors by thinking of the solution for you, even as an outline or pseudo-algorithm/code. And you'd probably be well beyond the definition of cheating if we did and you used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your words are separated by spaces, `split()` will work for you.
Check this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main():
    textFileName = 'C:\\temp\\001.txt'
    total = 0
    for line in open(textFileName):

        total += len(line.split())
    print(total, "words")
main()
```

OUTPUT:

```
(33, 'words')
```

EDIT:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def main():
    textFileName = 'C:\\temp\\001.txt'
    total = 0
    for line in open(textFileName):
        line = str.strip(line)
        for char in line:
            if char == ' ':
                total += 1
        total += 1
    print(total, "words")
main()
```

OUTPUT:
    (33, 'words')

`str.strip()` will remove tab as well.

```
In[2]: a='\tabc'
In[3]: print a
    abc
In[4]: str.strip(a)
Out[4]: 'abc'
```

Comment: Didn't the OP say that `split()` is not allowed?

Comment: @m1708997017 Although this does work, frustrating enough we're not allowed to use basically most Python functionality such as len() or split()

Comment: @SergioMolina So you can use str.strip(). Can you use str.split()? I'm talking about split() function in str module.

Comment: @m170897017 You cannot, basically just loops and str.strip(), not even len().

Comment: @SergioMolina OK. You only need plus one after each line. Check my update.

Comment: @m170897017 I'm still getting the same result as my original program unfortunately using your edit.

Comment: @SergioMolina Does content of file look the same as mentioned in your question? I got (33, 'words') from my side with edited program.

Comment: This does not handle multiple sequences of whitespace in between words, e.g. "Words     make up other words." will count as 9 words, not 5.

Comment: @mhawke I think he didn't mention there are more than one space between words.

Comment: @m170897017 - it is an obvious variation on the sample data that should be properly handled.

Comment: @m170897017 The 5th line in the text file uses tab instead of spaces, I edited and corrected that.

Comment: @SergioMolina There is no difference between using tab and spaces. Check my updated answer. Don't try to apply this program on content other than that in your question. This program only works for the content in your question.

Comment: @mhawke There is no need to answer a question he didn't ask. You can post your answer as you like to see what responses you will get.

Comment: @m170897017 - the sample data shown in the question is merely _one_ of the OP's sample files. It is _very_ likely that others will have multiple spaces. In general, a generic solution is better than a specific one tailored to a single example.

Comment: @m170897017 Your code is more along the lines of how I would approach it so I'll use yours as the answer. For some strange reason I'm still getting 34 but it's most likely on my side. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial if you could use `split()`:

```
def count_words(s):
    return len(s.split())
```

So implement your own version of `split()`, something like this:

```
import string

def splitter(s, sep=string.whitespace):
    words = []
    word = []
    for c in s:
        if c not in sep:
            word.append(c)
        else:
            if word:
                words.append(''.join(word))
                word = []
    if word:    # handle case of no sep at end of string
        words.append(''.join(word))
    return words
```

Now you can rewrite `count_words()`:

```
def count_words(s):
    return len(splitter(s))
```

Running this on your sample input:

```
>>> s = '''Words make up other words. 
This is a line.
  Sequences of words make sentences.
I like words but I don't like MS Word.
    There's another word for how I feel about MSWord: @#%&'''

>>> splitter(s)
['Words', 'make', 'up', 'other', 'words.', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'line.', 'Sequences', 'of', 'words', 'make', 'sentences.', 'I', 'like', 'words', 'but', 'I', "don't", 'like', 'MS', 'Word.', "There's", 'another', 'word', 'for', 'how', 'I', 'feel', 'about', 'MSWord:', '@#%&']
>>> count_words(s)
33
```

---

**Edit**: Not allowed to use `append()` or `join()`:

```
def splitter(s, sep=string.whitespace):
    words = []
    word = ''
    for c in s:
        if c not in sep:
            word += c
        else:
            if word:
                words += [word]
                word = ''
    if word:    # handle case of no sep at end of string
        words += [word]
    return words

def count_words(s):
    count = 0
    for word in splitter(s):
        count += 1
    return count

>>> splitter(s)
['Words', 'make', 'up', 'other', 'words.', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'line.', 'Sequences', 'of', 'words', 'make', 'sentences.', 'I', 'like', 'words', 'but', 'I', "don't", 'like', 'MS', 'Word.', "There's", 'another', 'word', 'for', 'how', 'I', 'feel', 'about', 'MSWord:', '@#%&']
>>> count_words(s)
33
```

And a more direct approach:

```
def count_words(s, sep=string.whitespace):
    count = 0 
    in_word = False
    for c in s:
        if c not in sep:
            if not in_word:
                count += 1
                in_word = True
        else:
            in_word = False
    return count
```

Comment: I can't use the append function, basically only _for_ and _while_ loops and str.strip().

Comment: @SergioMolina : can you use `+` style list and string concatenation? How about `join()`?

Comment: You can't use join(), and you can use string concatenation

Comment: @SergioMolina : also removed `len()` from `count_words()`

Comment: @SergioMolina Did you mean to accept this answer? You seem to have accepted another.